# How do I create the right path to put a header image in my CSS file?

Tags: html, css, image, header, background-image

The CSS file path is Website/common/msm.css

The image I want to use is Website/images/msm.jpeg

Here is my code:
`header /* Header Image */`

```
background-image:url('../images/msm.jpeg');
    width:80%;
    height:8em;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

So far, I see the height difference on my webpage, but the image doesn't display.

Comment: If you've downloaded the image through Chrome, please check the privileges of the image. Chrome has a bug that makes images unusable by changing the privileges-setting of downloads and since you use CSS to add it, it won't show up as a "broken link". Change the privileges so everybody can read the file, writing is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I created the image in a microsoft paint document, so privileges shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: ../ out one more time. to go into the Website folder. Then go into images folder to find the image.

Comment: I tried: `background-image:url('../../images/msm.jpeg');` but it's not displaying.

Comment: @dowomenfart That shouldn't be the problem, as he is in folder `B` in `A/B/file` and he has to go to `C` in `A/C/file`. Going back once will put him in folder `A`, so going back once should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

My CSS is:

`header /* Header Image tba */
    {
        background-position:center;
        position:relative;
        height:10%;
        width:80%;
        display:inline-block;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-image: url("../images/logo.png");
        background-size: contain;
    }`

At different points, it was too big or too small to show up, which is why I included the "background-size" line.